# Can't delete files from SD drive

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

My preferred laptop won't delete files from SD cards. This is NOT a function of the card - I can delete files if I use a different machine. It is not the card adapter - the same adapter and card work on the other laptop. Although the properties tab shows the card as read-only, I can copy new files onto to the card, so it's not really read-only. If I try to untick the read-only box, the next time I look, it still shows read-only. I've tried using attrib to change the attribute, but that has no effect. I've tried diskpart. I've tried the registry key suggested on numerous websites. Controlled folder access is off. I've deleted and restored the driver. What else can I try?

Windows 10, 64 bit, build 19044.1766

Comment: Have you tried deleting the files in powershell? Just to see what error message comes up if failed. You want to run powershell as administrator and then go with `Remove-Item -Path "ExactPathToYourItem" -Force -Recurse`. If it's a folder you're deleting the Recurse option will delete everything inside that folder.

Comment: Try using DISM and SFC to make sure there's not issue with the OS on that machine. Also try using an external USB card reader if you're using the built-in reader in a laptop, or tryb a different external reader if already using one, even if that reader works on another PC: Windows occasionally does not deal with with removing and reinserting a USB device.

Comment: @Mastaxx - Here's the error message from trying to delete in admin powershell - remove-item : Cannot remove item F:\dcim\302PRIME\gambol oak.JPG: The media is write protected.
At line:1 char:1
+ remove-item -path '.\gambol oak.JPG'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (F:\dcim\302PRIME\gambol oak.JPG:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I have run DSIM and SFC and the machine comes up clean. I've tried too different external card adapters and have the same results on each. Those same two card adapters work on a different laptop.

Comment: Two more suggestions: plug the card reader *into a different USB port*, and/or delete the USB device history, https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-Record-of-USB-Plug-in-Equipment . [BTW, always eject a USB drive before removing it... forgetting *sometimes* causes locking, loss of data, or even device damage.]

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I tried both of these suggestions. Neither fixed the issue.